# Check if module exists, if not install it

Tags: python, module, import

I want to check if a module exists, if it doesn't I want to install it.

How should I do this?

So far I have this code which correctly prints `f` if the module doesn't exist.

```
try:
    import keyring
except ImportError:
    print 'f'
```

Comment: This will work in a script and check whether a module exists, but installing the module is a different case altogether.

Comment: turns out using os.system() works.

Comment: subprocess.Popen is preferred to os.system.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a module is installed in Python and, if not, install it within the code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44210656/how-to-check-if-a-module-is-installed-in-python-and-if-not-install-it-within-t)

Comment: This question is very old, and most answers, including the accepted ones and the trending ones, are outdated. I think [the best, most up-to-date answer is in a duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44210735/3873799). For this reason, I chose to flag this question as duplicate instead of the newer one. People should be forwarded to the newer copy.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is how it should be done, and if I am wrong, please correct me. However, Noufal seems to confirm it in another answer to this question, so I guess it's right.

When writing the `setup.py` script for some scripts I wrote, I was dependent on the package manager of my distribution to install the required library for me.

So, in my `setup.py` file, I did this:

```
package = 'package_name'
try:
    return __import__(package)
except ImportError:
    return None
```

So if `package_name` was installed, fine, continue. Else, install it via the package manager which I called using `subprocess`.

Comment: This is useful in principle, however it does not highlight a possible implementation of `__import__()`. See this answer for it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44210735/3873799

Answer (score 52):

```
import pip

def import_or_install(package):
    try:
        __import__(package)
    except ImportError:
        pip.main(['install', package])
```

This code simply attempt to import a package, where package is of type **str**, and if it is unable to, calls pip and attempt to install it from there.

Comment: This looks like a much more modern solution, but doesn't handle version pinning at all. I wonder how that would be done...?

Comment: When I use this code I get `Permission denied error`.

Comment: Try doing `pip.main(['install', '--user', package])`.

Comment: It doesn't work for me I get the next error "{module 'pip' has no attribute 'main'}"

Comment: For packages where their import and install names are different, I sent two variables: `pkg_name` and `pip_name`. For example:

`pip install google-api-python-client`
`import googleapiclient`

Comment: how to get this to work with ``"from email import policy"``

Comment: I think this is an improper solution; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44210735/3873799 and its comments.

Answer (score 14):

**NOTE**: Ipython / Jupyter specific solution.

While using notebooks / online kernels, I usually do it using [systems call](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html).

```
try:
  import keyring
except:
  !pip install keyring
  import keyring
```

P.S. One may wish to call `conda install` or `mamba install` instead.

Comment: what is `!pip install pulp` ?

Comment: IPython runs any command starting with `!` on the shell .. 
Read this [link](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/01.05-ipython-and-shell-commands.html#Shell-Commands-in-IPython).
Thus, `!pip install pulp` will install pulp using pip from within jupyter

Comment: This question is not about IPython/Jupyer, and even then a better solution is to invoke with the `!` a `subprocess` command, as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/44210735/3873799

Answer (score 11):

This approach of dynamic import work really well in cases you just want to print a message if module is not installed. Automatically installing a module **SHOULDN'T** be done like issuing pip via `subprocess`. That's why we have setuptools (or distribute).

We have some great tutorials on packaging, and the task of dependencies detection/installation is as simple as providing `install_requires=[ 'FancyDependency', 'otherFancy>=1.0' ]`. That's just it!

But, if you really **NEED** to do by hand, you can use `setuptools` to help you.

```
from pkg_resources import WorkingSet , DistributionNotFound
working_set = WorkingSet()

# Printing all installed modules
print tuple(working_set)

# Detecting if module is installed
try:
    dep = working_set.require('paramiko>=1.0')
except DistributionNotFound:
    pass

# Installing it (anyone knows a better way?)
from setuptools.command.easy_install import main as install
install(['django>=1.2'])
```

Comment: Here's a [snapshot](https://web.archive.org/web/20140715201828/http://guide.python-distribute.org/) of the dead link.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `os.system` as follows:

```
import os

package = "package_name"

try:
    __import__package
except:
    os.system("pip install "+ package)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can launch `pip install %s"%keyring` in the except part to do this but I don't recommend it. The correct way is to package your application using [distutils](http://docs.python.org/library/distutils.html) so that when it's installed, dependencies will be pulled in.

Comment: distutils doesn't actually specify dependency information. You need to use setuptools or distribute in order to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

Not all modules can be installed so easily. Not all of them have easy-install support, some can only be installed by building them.. others require some non-python prerequisites, like gcc, which makes things even more complicated (and forget about it working well on Windows).

So I would say you could probably make it work for some predetermined modules, but there's no chance it'll be something generic that works for any module.

Answer (score 1):

I made an `import_neccessary_modules()` function to fix this common issue.

```
# ======================================================================================
# == Fix any missing Module, that need to be installed with PIP.exe. [Windows System] ==
# ======================================================================================
import importlib, os
def import_neccessary_modules(modname:str)->None:
    '''
        Import a Module,
        and if that fails, try to use the Command Window PIP.exe to install it,
        if that fails, because PIP in not in the Path,
        try find the location of PIP.exe and again attempt to install from the Command Window.
    '''
    try:
        # If Module it is already installed, try to Import it
        importlib.import_module(modname)
        print(f"Importing {modname}")
    except ImportError:
        # Error if Module is not installed Yet,  the '\033[93m' is just code to print in certain colors
        print(f"\033[93mSince you don't have the Python Module [{modname}] installed!")
        print("I will need to install it using Python's PIP.exe command.\033[0m")
        if os.system('PIP --version') == 0:
            # No error from running PIP in the Command Window, therefor PIP.exe is in the %PATH%
            os.system(f'PIP install {modname}')
        else:
            # Error, PIP.exe is NOT in the Path!! So I'll try to find it.
            pip_location_attempt_1 = sys.executable.replace("python.exe", "") + "pip.exe"
            pip_location_attempt_2 = sys.executable.replace("python.exe", "") + "scripts\pip.exe"
            if os.path.exists(pip_location_attempt_1):
                # The Attempt #1 File exists!!!
                os.system(pip_location_attempt_1 + " install " + modname)
            elif os.path.exists(pip_location_attempt_2):
                # The Attempt #2 File exists!!!
                os.system(pip_location_attempt_2 + " install " + modname)
            else:
                # Neither Attempts found the PIP.exe file, So i Fail...
                print(f"\033[91mAbort!!!  I can't find PIP.exe program!")
                print(f"You'll need to manually install the Module: {modname} in order for this program to work.")
                print(f"Find the PIP.exe file on your computer and in the CMD Command window...")
                print(f"   in that directory, type    PIP.exe install {modname}\033[0m")
                exit()


import_neccessary_modules('art')
import_neccessary_modules('pyperclip')
import_neccessary_modules('winsound')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach. The idea is loop until python has already installed all modules by built in module as "pip" .

```
import pip

while True:
    
    try:
        #import your modules here. !
        import seaborn
        import bokeh

        break

    except ImportError as err_mdl:
        
        print((err_mdl.name))
        pip.main(['install', err_mdl.name])
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried installing transformers using the below method and it worked fine. Similarly, you can just replace your library name instead of "transformers".

```py
import pip
try:
    from transformers import pipeline
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    pip.main(['install', "transformers"])
    from transformers import pipeline
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in a new virtual envoirnment with no packages installed and it installed the necessary package i.e. `opencv-python`
Example is given below

```
import os

try:
    import cv2
except ImportError:
    os.system('pip install opencv-python')
```