# Pyspark --py-files doesn't work

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, emr

I use this as document suggests http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.1/submitting-applications.html

spsark version 1.1.0

```
./spark/bin/spark-submit --py-files /home/hadoop/loganalysis/parser-src.zip \
/home/hadoop/loganalysis/ship-test.py
```

and conf in code :

```
conf = (SparkConf()
        .setMaster("yarn-client")
        .setAppName("LogAnalysis")
        .set("spark.executor.memory", "1g")
        .set("spark.executor.cores", "4")
        .set("spark.executor.num", "2")
        .set("spark.driver.memory", "4g")
        .set("spark.kryoserializer.buffer.mb", "128"))
```

and slave node complain ImportError

```
14/12/25 05:09:53 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, ip-172-31-10-8.cn-north-1.compute.internal): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hadoop/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 75, in main
    command = pickleSer._read_with_length(infile)
  File "/home/hadoop/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 150, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
ImportError: No module named parser
```

and parser-src.zip is tested locally.

```
[hadoop@ip-172-31-10-231 ~]$ python
Python 2.7.8 (default, Nov  3 2014, 10:17:30) 
[GCC 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-16)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.insert(1, '/home/hadoop/loganalysis/parser-src.zip')
>>> from parser import parser
>>> parser.parse
<function parse at 0x7fa5ef4c9848>
>>>
```

I'm trying to get info about the remote worker. see whether it copied the files.what the sys.path looks like..and it's tricky.

UPDATE:
I use this found that the zip file was shiped. and sys.path was set. still import get error.

```
data = list(range(4))
disdata = sc.parallelize(data)
result = disdata.map(lambda x: "sys.path:  {0}\nDIR: {1}   \n FILES: {2} \n parser: {3}".format(sys.path, os.getcwd(), os.listdir('.'), str(parser)))
result.collect()
print(result.take(4))
```

it seems I have to digging into cloudpickle.which means I need to understand how cloudpickle works and fails first.

```
: An error occurred while calling o40.collect.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 4 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 4.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 23, ip-172-31-10-8.cn-north-1.compute.internal): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hadoop/spark/python/pyspark/worker.py", line 75, in main
    command = pickleSer._read_with_length(infile)
  File "/home/hadoop/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 150, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/home/hadoop/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 811, in subimport
    __import__(name)
ImportError: ('No module named parser', <function subimport at 0x7f219ffad7d0>, ('parser.parser',))
```

UPDATE:

someone encounter the same problem in spark 0.8
http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/pyspark-Importing-other-py-files-in-PYTHONPATH-td2301.html

but he put his lib in python dist-packages and import works. which I tried and still get import error.

UPDATE:

OH.gush.. I think the problem is caused by not understanding zip file and python import behaviour..I pass parser.py to --py-files, it works, complain about another dependency.
and zip only the .py files[not including .pyc] seems to work too.

But I couldn't quite understand why though.

Answer (score 14):

Try this function of `SparkContext`

```
sc.addPyFile(path)
```

According to `pyspark` documentation [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html)

> Add a .py or .zip dependency for all tasks to be executed on this SparkContext in the future. The path passed can be either a local file, a file in HDFS (or other Hadoop-supported filesystems), or an HTTP, HTTPS or FTP URI.

Try upload your python module file to a public cloud storage (e.g. AWS S3) and pass the URL to that method.

Here is a more comprehensive reading material: http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/spark_python.html

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for ! Thanks !

Answer (score 10):

Try to import your custom module from inside the method itself rather than at the top of the driver script, e.g.:

```
def parse_record(record):
    import parser
    p = parser.parse(record)
    return p
```

rather than

```
import parser
def parse_record(record):
    p = parser.parse(record)
    return p
```

Cloud Pickle doesn't seem to recognise when a custom module has been imported, so it seems to try to pickle the top-level modules along with the other data that's needed to run the method. In my experience, this means that top-level modules appear to exist, but they lack usable members, and nested modules can't be used as expected. Once either importing with `from A import *` or from inside the method (`import A.B`), the modules worked as expected.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like one or more of the nodes aren't configured properly. Do all of the nodes on the cluster have the same version/configuration of Python (i.e. they all have the parser module installed)?

If you don't want to check one-by-one you could write a script to check if it is installed/install it for you. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527554/check-if-module-exists-if-not-install-it-in-python) thread shows a few ways to do that.

Comment: i use aws emr, and have bootstrap-action script for all nodes.and they all have the exact same configure/version. all have Python 2.7.8.

Answer (score 1):

PySpark on EMR is configured for Python 2.6 by default, so make sure they're not being installed for the Python 2.7 interpreter

Answer (score 1):

You need to package your Python code using tools like setuptools. This will let you create an .egg file which is similar to java jar file. You can then specify the path of this egg file using --py-files

spark-submit --py-files path_to_egg_file   path_to_spark_driver_file

Answer (score 1):

Create zip files (example- abc.zip) containing all your dependencies.

While creating the spark context mention the zip file name as:

```
    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf, pyFiles=["abc.zip"])
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar kind of problem, My worker nodes could not detect the modules even though I was using the `--py-files` switch.

There were couple of things I did - First I tried putting import statement after I created SparkContext (sc) variable hoping that import should take place after the module has shipped to all nodes but still it did not work. I then tried `sc.addFile` to add the module inside the script itself (instead of sending it as a command line argument) and afterwards imported the functions of the module. This did the trick at least in my case.

Comment: How did you reference these from your main python script?

Comment: @CarlosBribiescas Did you mean which path did I use for the modules? I just mentioned the absolute path of my module.py file in sc.addFile(pathname)

Comment: That doesn't work on cluster because --py-files uploads them to a different directory on the server.  I ended up referencing them by using execfile("./__pyfiles__/module.py") which i guess this is where spark-submit puts the files.

Comment: @CarlosBribiescas When I mean the path of the module. I do not check for the path where py-files uploads them on the server. I do not use the py-files switch at all. I just used sc.addFile(filepath) where filepath was the path of my module which i had created and had saved somewhere on my local disk.