# Importing custom accumulator types in Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, import, pyspark, accumulator

I'm trying to use a custom accumulator class as per the [Spark documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#accumulators). This works if I define the class locally, but when I try define it in another module and import the file using `sc.addPyFile` I get an `ImportError`.

I had the same issue when importing a helper function within an `rdd.foreach`, which I was able to resolve by performing the `import` *within* the foreach'd function (example to follow) as per [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27644525/pyspark-py-files-doesnt-work). However, the same fix doesn't work for the custom accumulator (and I wouldn't really expect it to).

tl;dr: What is the proper way to import a custom accumulator class?

extensions/accumulators.py:

```
class ArrayAccumulatorParam(pyspark.AccumulatorParam):
    def zero(self, initialValue):
        return numpy.zeros(initialValue.shape)

    def addInPlace(self, a, b):
        a += b
        return a
```

run/count.py:

```
from extensions.accumulators import ArrayAccumulatorParam

def main(sc):
    sc.addPyFile(LIBRARY_PATH + '/import_/logs.py')
    sc.addPyFile(LIBRARY_PATH + '/extensions/accumulators.py')

    rdd = sc.textFile(LOGS_PATH)
    accum = sc.accumulator(numpy.zeros(DIMENSIONS), ArrayAccumulatorParam())

    def count(row)
        import logs # This 'internal import' seems to be required to avoid ImportError for the 'logs' module
        from extensions.accumulators import ArrayAccumulatorParam # Error is thrown both with and without this line

        val = logs.parse(row)
        accum.add(val)

    rdd.foreach(count) # Throws ImportError: No module named extensions.accumulators

if __name__ == '__main__':
    conf = pyspark.SparkConf().setAppName('SOME_COUNT_JOB')
    sc = pyspark.SparkContext(conf=conf)
    main(sc)
```

Error:

```
ImportError: No module named extensions.accumulators
```

Comment: for custom accumulators use (pyspark.accumulators.AccumulatorParam)