# Importing from local directory in python

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-zeppelin

I am a bit confused about why the error happens for the following case:

I got the following project:

```
home/projects/project1
```

and:

```
user:home/projects/project1$ ls
file1.py
file2.py
__init__.py
data
```

where data is a folder with some files.

And I do the following:

```
from os import path
import sys
sys.path.append(path.abspath('/home/projects/project1'))    

from file1 import function1
```

That works. 
Also `import file2` works fine.

`file1` is depentant of some fuctions of `file2`. Such as `file1` starts with:

```
from file2 import function2
```

So when I call:

```
res = function1(some_input)
```

I get the following error:

```
File "/home/dimitris/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 434, in loads
return pickle.loads(obj)
ImportError: No module named file2
```

Why is this happening?

**EDIT**

Not sure if its relevant but I am making this module and trying to import it in apache-zeppelin notebook to use them there. And there is where I get the error.

It seems that it could be related to this question: [Pyspark --py-files doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27644525/pyspark-py-files-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 1):

You probably have the `import file2` statement at the beginning of `file1.py`. If you would `import file1`, it would load the whole module, but since you import just a function - you miss the dependency.

You can fix it by either `import file1` or by adding `import file2` statement at the beginning of `function1` definition. E.g,

```
# file1.py
def function1(some_input):
    import file2
    .. your code ..
```

Comment: I would expect this to be working. Still having the same error.

Comment: You get the same error? Not a different one? It's not a good design to have such a dependency, if you must - import the whole module and access your function using full path: `file2.function1()`. At least for testing, see if it works.

Comment: I have access to run individually `import file2; file2.function2()`. But still I got this error when  trying to run `file1.function1()` which depends on `file2.function2()`. I have updated my question by questioning if there is somethign that I use apache-zeppelin.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

file1.py:

```
def hello():
    print('hello from file1')
```

file2.py:

```
import file1 as f
def get_hello():
    return f.hello()
```