# How to catch a python ImportError as a Shell error

Tags: python, bash, shell

I have a following script which checks whether a python module is installed or not.

```
{

ipython -c 'from package import module' && echo "Successful import"

} || echo "package not found!"
```

This is a typlical `try..catch` syntax of bash. If the command before && would work it will execute the command after that otherwise execute the command after ||.

But in this case, whether `package` is installed or not, or should I say whether the command

```
ipython -c 'from package import module'
```

returns `None` or `ImportError`, bash reads it as successful execution and prints "Successful import"

How can I check for a successful import of a python package using bash?

EDIT : And return with exit status 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least two possibilities:

- Using "pip" on your shell script to get the list of installed packages then grep for tour package:

  pip list |  grep yourpackage && echo installed || echo "NOT Installed"
- Using Python-bash script, I don't know exactly how to call it but I know how to use it:

Something like:

```
output=$(
python - <<EOF
try:
    import your_package;
    print "Package Installed"
except Exception:
    print "Package not installed"
EOF
)

echo $output
```

here you have alot of alternatives to check for the existence of the package/module, so, intead of trying to import the package, you can check it's existence in a pythonic way. You can grab the different solutions for this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050281/how-to-check-if-a-python-module-exists-without-importing-it) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527554/check-if-module-exists-if-not-install-it-in-python) and replace the `import your_package;` with one of them.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the exception `SystemExit(msg=None)` with any message that's not `None` or `0`. If it's uncaught, it'll cause the program to end, and if the `msg` is not `None` or `0`, with an exit code of `1`. (see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#SystemExit).

test.py

```
try:
    import Blue
except ImportError:
    raise SystemExit("Import Error!")
```

in bash:

```
[user]@[host] $ python test.py 
Import Error!

[user]@[host] $ python test.py || echo "blarg"
Import Error!
blarg

[user]@[host] $ python test.py && echo "blarg"
Import Error!
```

Comment: That helped. But It's not exiting with status 1. How can I do that?

Comment: The python process does. That's why the first `echo` is executed but the second one is not.

Comment: @HimanshuMishra Are you calling python with `python` or `ipython`?

Comment: Yes. I'm sorry. I checked it with `echo $?` and it gave me the status `1`. But, I'm running this on travis and it exits with status 0. I'm running this with python.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `python` command for running code snippets programmatically, instead of `ipython`.

There's an outstanding bug about this:
https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/6912