# How to check what modules are installed with Python script

Tags: python

I have a Python script that export some data from mssql server. I use the pyodbc module.
Before i run my Python script i want to check if the pyodbc modules exists and if not to install it as we do with pip install pyodbc. What is the correct approach to do this?

Comment: i think this was solved here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44210656/how-to-check-if-a-module-is-installed-in-python-and-if-not-install-it-within-t

Answer (score 0):

i did in this way:

```
import os
while True:
    try:
        import pyodbc
        print("pyodbc imported")
        break
    except:
        print(os.popen("pip install pyodbc").read())
        continue

print("the rest of your script here")
```

when you run this code the output is:

```
C:\projects>python autoinstall.py
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.1; however, version 20.2.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'c:\python38-32\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Collecting pyodbc
  Using cached pyodbc-4.0.30-cp38-cp38-win32.whl (58 kB)
Installing collected packages: pyodbc
Successfully installed pyodbc-4.0.30

pyodbc imported
the rest of your script here
```

in this way it will install any missing module and start the code in one run.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the subprocess module to execute pip list to get a list of the installed modules and check if it contains the pyodbc module.

```
import subprocess

module_list = subprocess.check_output(['pip', 'list'])

if b'pyodbc' in module_list:
    import pyodbc
    # your code here
```